# WebStorm JavaScript debugger: how to compress debugging messages

Tags: webstorm, jetbrains-ide

Recently I found that I can easily debug JavaScript application using Debugging tool in WebStorm. One problem I found it that debug messages are printed in WebStorm console without being collapsed/compressed.

For example, in Chrome dev-tools errors are presented this way:

[image]

and if the develop wants to get more details, he/she can click the small arrow and get a full stack trace.

However, I don't see how watching compressed errors is possible in WebStorm. I just see a full stack trace for every error:

[image]

It's really hard to read console and understand what is going on. 
Do you know a way to see errors compressed in WebStorm as I see them in Chrome dev tools?

Answer (score 1):

Not currently possible, please vote for [IDEABKL-3271](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-3271) to be notified on any progress with this feature